# Why are cryptographic hash functions apparently easier to create than lossless compression schemes?

Tags: information-theory, cryptography, compression

Both cryptographic hash functions and lossless compression schemes map certain long sequences of bits to shorter sequences of bits. Theoretically, lossless compressions schemes are injective, while hash functions are not.

However, by design, cryptographic hash functions are considered injective if their domain is restricted to only sequences of bits useful to humans. For example, [this answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4014407/2640937) creatively describes the chance of an SHA-256 collision. Practically, if all of the files ever generated by humans and ever to be generated by humans were hashed with SHA-256, there would almost certainly be no collisions.

State of the art general lossless compression algorithms can be expected to compress a general file (i.e. a sequence of bits useful to a human) to about 0.8 times the size on average.

SHA-256 compresses *every* file to just 256 bits. No existing lossless compression algorithm can compress every file to just 256 bits. The only problem is that it's not easily reversible, also by design.

So why is it apparently much harder to make a reversible, practically injective function than an irreversible, practically injective function from long sequences of bits to short sequences of bits?

Comment: "lossless compression schemes map long sequences of bits to shorter sequences of bits." By a simple counting argument, this cannot be true. It might be true for most sequences of bits that are useful to humans, but there are $2^n$ different sequences of bits of length $n$, and only $2^n-1$ sequences of bits that are shorter, so even a compression algorithm specifically tailored to only sequences of length $n$ can't compress all of them losslessy.

Comment: @Arthur Of course. I've changed the wording to acknowledge this fact.

Comment: "cryptographic hash functions are considered injective if their domain is restricted to only sequences of bits useful to humans"
That's rather misleading. They are practically injective because the number of inputs (
sequences of bits) actually used are very small compared with the output range $2^{256}$.

Comment: @leonbloy The set of sequences of bits useful to humans is a superset of the set of sequences of bits used as input to cryptographic hashes. But, the set of sequences of bits useful to humans is also very small campared to the output range. At least, that's what I meant to communicate.

Comment: "Useful to humans" is the same as "used by humans" ? Your expression seems to imply that "useful to humans" is some inherent property of those sequences. It's not. Say today I generated a file of 1MB pseudo random bytes and uploaded it to Dropbox. That file happens to be useful to me (I plan to use it in my IT course, to do some simulations), and probably Dropbox will hash it (it matters that there is no collissions). But, in itself, it's pure random bits.